# How to have children components have access to parent components method in VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button which performs form validation that is in my parent component. This button if successful renders a child component that makes a call to an API. The problem is that when I change the input, the display changes simultaneously. I'm trying to have the animeFind function in the parent component so that my child component just takes care of UI and knowing which data to display (ie sometimes response.data["title"] or response.data["image_url"].

Parent component

```js
<template>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="parent-1">
      <h1 class="title is-1">Compare two animes! :)</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <b-field class="label" label="Anime 1">
          <b-input value="Enter the first anime!" v-model="anime1"></b-input>
        </b-field>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <b-field class="label" label="Anime 2">
          <b-input value="Enter the second anime!" v-model="anime2"></b-input>
        </b-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-spacing">
      <b-button class="button" type="is-primary" @click="checkComplete"
        >Compare!</b-button
      >
    </div>

    <Info :anime1="anime1" :anime2="anime2" v-if="success"></Info>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import Buefy from "buefy";
import "buefy/dist/buefy.css";
import Info from "./Info.vue";
Vue.use(Buefy);

export default {
  components: {
    Info,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      anime1: "",
      anime2: "",
      success: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    checkComplete() {
      if (this.anime1.length > 0 && this.anime2.length > 0) {
        this.success = true;
        return this.$buefy.toast.open({
          message: "Yay, just a moment now!",
          type: "is-success",
          position: "is-bottom",
          duration: 3000,
        });
      }
      this.success = false;
      return this.$buefy.toast.open({
        duration: 3000,
        message: `Please fill out both fields`,
        position: "is-bottom",
        type: "is-danger",
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Child component

```js
<template>
  <section>
    <img :src="url1" alt="./assets/notFound.png" />
    <img :src="url2" alt="./assets/notFound.png" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  props: {
    anime1: String,
    anime2: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url1: "",
      url2: "",
      error: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    animeFind(anime, data) {
      axios
        .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=${anime}`)
        .then((response) => {
          const id = response.data["results"][0]["mal_id"];
          axios
            .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/${id}`)
            .then((response) => (this[data] = response.data["image_url"]));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.error = error; // take care of this later
        });
    },
  },

  watch: {
    anime1: {
      immediate: true,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.animeFind(newVal, "url1");
      },
    },
    anime2: {
      immediate: true,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.animeFind(newVal, "url2");
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: To be clear. You want to move `animeFind` to the parent component, and when `checkComplete` function `returns true`; you need to call `animeFind` and make request with axios, IF axios gives a success response, you need to pass the `response.data` to the child function and render. Am I Correct?

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 0):

> **Note :**
> I have commented out the axios request and returned a image
> url always, to make this example work here.

```js
Vue.component('compare-anim', {
  template: '#tmpl-compare-anim',
  data() {
    return {
      anime1: "",
      anime2: "",
      url1: "",
      url2: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkComplete() {
    
      if (this.anime1.length > 0 && this.anime2.length > 0) {
        this.animeFind(this.anime1, 'url1');
        this.animeFind(this.anime2, 'url2');
      }
    },
    
    animeFind(anime, urlName) {
      var responseImg = this.makeRequest(anime);

      if (responseImg !== null) {
        this[urlName] = responseImg;
      }
    },
    
    makeRequest(anime) {
    
      //Not gonna make axios request; returning sample image url
      //in order to test this implementation
      return "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/monarch.png";
      /**
      axios
      .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=${anime}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const id = response.data["results"][0]["mal_id"];
        axios
          .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/${id}`)
          .then((response) => ( 
            return response.data["image_url"]) 
          );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error; // take care of this later
        return null;
      });
      **/
    }
  }
});


Vue.component('render-anim', {
  template: '#tmpl-render-anim',
  props : {
    url1 : {
      default: function () {
        return "";
      }
    },
    url2 : {
      default: function () {
        return "";
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {

  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <compare-anim></compare-anim>
</div>


<template id="tmpl-compare-anim">
  <section class="hero">
    <h1 class="title is-1">Compare two animes! :)</h1>
    <input placeholder="Enter the first anime!" v-model="anime1" /><br/><br/>
    <input placeholder="Enter the second anime!" v-model="anime2" /><br/><br/>
    <button class="button" type="is-primary" @click="checkComplete">Compare!</button>
    
    <render-anim :url1="url1" :url2="url2"></render-anim>
  </section>
</template>

<template id="tmpl-render-anim">
  <section>
    <img :src="url1" v-if="url1" alt="./assets/notFound.png" width="100" />
    <img :src="url2" v-if="url1" alt="./assets/notFound.png" width="100" />
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: What does the template id do, does it make sure that the variables declared in the vue component are accessible with any tags that are in the template?

Comment: No. template id is to identify which template belongs to which component. you don't have to add them in your code. it has nothing to do with any variables of the components

Comment: Is there a way to modularize this code, because if I start adding more vue components it's going to get really large, how would i have render-anim and compare-anim in different files? Or would you not recommend me doing this

Comment: you can add them in different files. it does not effect the implementation. I have added this in same file because I can't have multiple files here and I wanted to make a run-able  code snippet. Let me know If you come across any issues

Comment: I'm getting an error that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'functional' of undefined`

Comment: where do you get the error. in which component? in which line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222117/discussion-between-a-k-m-adib-and-chathuranga-k).